# Remove according to the pattern matching

Tags: postgresql, string-function

The current raw data :

```
1-2-05.11
1-15-05.20
```

how can I remove after `.`. The expected result is `1-2-05.` I test using  split_part and also substring, but the result is not fit the requirement. 
Any suggestion ?

Comment: What is the data type ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,I assume that your expected output is `1-2-05.`(with `.`)

Using split_part().

```
SELECT SPLIT_PART('1-2-05.11','.',1)||'.';
```

Using substring().

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('1-15-05.20', 1, LENGTH('1-15-05.20') - 2)
```

- `1` is the starting position(*from left*) of the string(`1-15-05.20`) in which substring action to be taken
- `LENGTH('1-15-05.20') - 2`, is to define the number of character to be extracted from the given string.The string is `1-15-05.20` the `length()` of it is `10`, you need to remove *last two* characters from this 10 chars so 10 - 2 ie `LENGTH('1-15-05.20') - 2`

Comment: Hi wingedpanther ! Both your formula running ! Can you explain for using substring especially on the length portion

Comment: @Samila I've updated the answer with the explanation, let me know if you need more info.